# Lowest k pairwise absolute differences

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a list of Integers and a number k. We have to return the k minimum absolute differences between different pairs of Integers in sorted order (ascending)
eg: If the Given list of integers is 6, 9, 1, and k=2 Then the output should be [3,5]
Because the pairwise absolute differences are: |6-9|=3, |6-1|=5, |9-1|=8 the lowest 2 in ascending order will be 3,5

I solved this problem in following ways:

1. Calculate the pairwise absolute difference-> sort the list -> return the first k elements
   Score: 7/15 Only 7 test cases passed out of 15. Rest I got Time Limit Exceeded Error
2. Instead of sorting I put all the elements in a min heap using the PriorityQueue in Java. The results were similar 8/15

Not sure what could be more efficient way to approach this problems. Any ideas?

Comment: You didn't show us any code.

Comment: Nor supplied the input that your code fails on, or showed us what output you are currently getting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In the solution mentioned, we first insert the adjacent elements diff into the heap. Then we are popping out the minimum absolute value, which will be the first minimal absolute difference. Now, if the (i,j) pair is the one that produced the min absolute difference, then as per the code, the next minimum absolute value will be produced by adding ((j+1),i) indexes absolute difference. I don't understand why this point is valid.

Answer (score 1):

- Sort the list first
- Init d = 1
- Then get the absolute difference between elements 'd' distance apart and insert into a min-k heap. Quit as soon as your heap got k elements.
- Go to step 3 with d = d + 1

Answer is in your heap. Complexity depends on k. If k ~ n^2, then it could be O(n^2) because you have to find all pairs. But it could be much better if k << n^2.

Comment: You need a little more logic, because the 3rd best pair need not be 2 adjacent elements.

Comment: You are right if k > n, I updated the answer, but I m almost sure there could be a better method. Thinking.